# MySQL stress test tool, remote server preferred

Tags: mysql, load-balancing, centos, mysqlslap

For MySQL stress test there exists programs:
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysqltest/2.0/en/test-programs.html

Also mysqlslap exists: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/mysqlslap.html

Is it possible to test remote server ?
With proper configuration to connect both servers, is it possible to make stress test from a remote server ?

Answer (score 1):

The vast majority of database benchmarking tools allow the user to specify a host and a login - [Hammerdb](http://hammerora.sourceforge.net/) does, as does [SysBench](https://launchpad.net/sysbench). The last programme on your first link also allows a host to be [specified](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysqltest/2.0/en/mysql-stress-test-pl.html).

Check out this [interesting link](http://www.percona.com/blog/2011/02/01/sample-datasets-for-benchmarking-and-testing/) for real test datasets.